# Too many open ports in Debian 8

Tags: linux, ports

The IT department has given me 3 virtual servers with Debian 8 for my area, which I will manage (but they have some monitoring tools).

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-11 13:33 ART
Nmap scan report for 192.168.x.53
Host is up (0.0043s latency).
Not shown: 983 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
1/tcp     open  tcpmux
22/tcp    open  ssh
79/tcp    open  finger
80/tcp    open  http
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
119/tcp   open  nntp
143/tcp   open  imap
1080/tcp  open  socks
1524/tcp  open  ingreslock
2000/tcp  open  cisco-sccp
6667/tcp  open  irc
12345/tcp open  netbus
31337/tcp open  Elite
32771/tcp open  sometimes-rpc5
32772/tcp open  sometimes-rpc7
32773/tcp open  sometimes-rpc9
32774/tcp open  sometimes-rpc11

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.28 seconds
jsivil@jsivil:~$ nmap 192.168.x.52

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-11 13:36 ART
Nmap scan report for 192.168.x.52
Host is up (0.0046s latency).
Not shown: 982 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
1/tcp     open  tcpmux
22/tcp    open  ssh
79/tcp    open  finger
80/tcp    open  http
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
119/tcp   open  nntp
143/tcp   open  imap
1080/tcp  open  socks
1524/tcp  open  ingreslock
2000/tcp  open  cisco-sccp
6667/tcp  open  irc
12345/tcp open  netbus
31337/tcp open  Elite
32771/tcp open  sometimes-rpc5
32772/tcp open  sometimes-rpc7
32773/tcp open  sometimes-rpc9
32774/tcp open  sometimes-rpc11
50000/tcp open  ibm-db2

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.53 seconds
jsivil@jsivil:~$ nmap 192.168.x.54

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-11 13:36 ART
Nmap scan report for 192.168.x.54
Host is up (0.0071s latency).
Not shown: 983 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
1/tcp     open  tcpmux
22/tcp    open  ssh
79/tcp    open  finger
80/tcp    open  http
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
119/tcp   open  nntp
143/tcp   open  imap
1080/tcp  open  socks
1524/tcp  open  ingreslock
2000/tcp  open  cisco-sccp
6667/tcp  open  irc
12345/tcp open  netbus
31337/tcp open  Elite
32771/tcp open  sometimes-rpc5
32772/tcp open  sometimes-rpc7
32773/tcp open  sometimes-rpc9
32774/tcp open  sometimes-rpc11

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.27 seconds
```

Its way too many open ports for me. In my Home, I have Ubuntu 14.04 servers and only port 22 and 80 are open.

What should I do? Are these ports risky?

Comment: If you manage these servers, then the simplest way for you to pursue your investigation would be to connect to this server and issue a `netstat -an` and `lsof -i TCP` to get more information about opened ports. However, under the current form, I fear the question might be too broad to be answerable.

Comment: You're not checking udp and ipv6?

Comment: [Also posted on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202780/too-many-open-ports-in-debian-8). [Don't do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all systems they should only run processes which are necessary for the operation of the system, to minimize their attack surface.

This is especially true for services which listen on the network as that is a common point of attack.

So the question here is, are all those ports required for the operation of your servers?  To establish that you can use commands like netstat and lsof (as @WhiteWinterWolf suggests in his comment) to see what programs on the server are using those ports.  I'd also recommend speaking to your IT department to see if they have a list of ports which they expect to be open and also to ask about their build process.

Some of the ones you've listed (e.g. 79/TCP for finger) are pretty unusual to see open on a server these days.  To me that's either a case of someone installing default packages without fully understanding the reason (I kind of doubt you're using finger in your organisation), or someone has installed another service which uses that port (this is generally considered bad practice for ports under 1024/TCP as they have a common well known service associated with them)

Once you've done that, if your IT department don't need them open for maintenance, and you've confirmed that you won't need the software in question, I would look at uninstalling the programs that are holding those ports open.

Comment: It seems to be that these ports are managed by an application called `portsentry`, which is used to monitor the ports and block port scanners.

Comment: hmm interesting, it didn't look (from the results you pasted in) as though your port scan got blocked, so I guess you might want to check with them that it's configured ok :)